# Given $r_1$ alphas and $r_2$ betas, probability that the arrangement contains exactly $k$ runs of either kind is

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This is a question from An Introduction to Probability By Feller (II.20).  Consider the arangement of $r_1$ alphas and $r_2$ betas and assume that all arrangements are equally probable, then show that the probability that the arrangement contains exactly $k$ runs of either kind is

$$
2\binom{r_1 - 1}{u-1} \binom{r_2 -1 }{u-1}\diagup \binom{r_1 + r_2}{r_1}
$$
when $k = 2u$ and
$$
\Bigg(\binom{r_1 - 1}{u} \binom{r_2 -1 }{u-1} + \binom{r_1-1}{u-1} \binom{r_2-1}{u}\Bigg)\diagup \binom{r_1 + r_2}{r_1}
$$
when $k = 2u+1$.

I am trying to solve this as follows. If there are $k$ alpha runs, then there can be $k-1,k,k+1$ beta runs.  Similarly, $k$ beta runs can result in $k-1,k,k+1$ alpha runs.  Hence in total there can be

$$
\frac{1}{\binom{r_1 + r_2}{r_1}} \Bigg[\binom{r_1 - 1}{k-1} \binom{r_2 -1 }{k-2} + \binom{r_1 - 1}{k-1} \binom{r_2 -1 }{k-1} + \binom{r_1 - 1}{k-1} \binom{r_2 -1 }{k} + \binom{r_1 - 1}{k-2} \binom{r_2 -1 }{k-1} + \binom{r_1 - 1}{k} \binom{r_2 -1 }{k-1} \Bigg ]
$$

But the above formula does not reduce to the answer in the book.  Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure you're interpreting the question correctly.  I think Feller means that there are $k$ runs in total.  For example, if $k=2$, then $u=1$ and the numerator in Feller's answer is $2$.  Indeed, all the $\alpha$s must come first or all the $\beta$s must come first.

Comment: You’ve misinterpreted the question: the expressions that you’re asked to prove make it clear that ‘exactly $k$ runs of either kind’ means ‘ a total of exactly $k$ runs altogether’. When $k=2u$ there must be $u$ runs of each letter, and when $k=2u+1$ there must be $u$ runs of one letter and $u+1$ of the other.